# 360 degrees panorama with mobile device sensor control

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

Are you familiar with these 360 degrees videos on Youtube? Here's [an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j81DDY4nvos), if you're not. Best of all try to view it on your mobile device. The movement of the camera is controlled by mobile device sensors.

I'm trying to do the same with images. I found this nice script [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wildpeaks/MWfwc/). All I did was changing the images:

```
var folder = "images/360_degrees/";
    var sides = [
        [folder + "back.png", 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0],
        [folder + "front.png", 100, 0, 0, 0, 1.57, 0],
        [folder + "left.png", 0, 0, -100, 0, 3.14, 0],
        [folder + "right.png", -100, 0, 0, 0, 4.71, 0 ],
        [folder + "bottom.png", 0, 100, 0, 4.71, 0, 0 ],
        [folder + "top.png", 0, -100, 0, 1.57, 0, 0 ]
    ];
```

However, I'm running into few issues with this script:

1. I want to make a specific image to be the center, meaning I want it to always open from the same "cube" side (that image) and make the rotation from this point. Is it possible to do that? After all, these videos always start from the same point...
2. Often (well, actually most of the time), when I'm done rotating my device, the motion of this cube continues by itself. How can I stop it once the device stopped moving?

Perhaps if there're any other codes online that do the same thing - I'll be glad to have a link to them too.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the following code,

```js
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(e) {

        camera.rotation.set (
            !e.beta  ? 0 : e.beta * deg2rad,
            !e.gamma ? 0 : e.gamma * deg2rad,
            !e.alpha ? 0 : e.alpha * deg2rad
        );
    }, false);
```

You'll see that the panaroma is static at one initial point.

Now tweak the value of,

```
cube.rotation.x = -90; // tweak it to 0, 30 etc
```

Like wise you get `y`,

```
cube.rotation.y = 0; // tweak it to 0, 30 etc
```

Tweaking above thing will answer your first question about how to start panorama from a particular point.

Answer to second question lies in the `deviceorientation` event listener.  You can defined a threshold when to change camera values.

```js
 // this can be any condition.
 if (  ( e.beta * deg2rad ) > 1.1  || ( e.gamma * deg2rad ) > 0.01 ) 
 {        
   camera.rotation.set (
     !e.beta  ? 0 : e.beta * deg2rad,
     !e.gamma ? 0 : e.gamma * deg2rad,
     !e.alpha ? 0 : e.alpha * deg2rad
   );
}
```

Comment: If I remove the `deviceorientation` event listener, than the cube wouldn't rotate at all (since it's no longer listens to the event, of course). I tried to add the `if` statement you suggested, but the cube continued to rotate. Is it possible there's a problem with my testing device?

Comment: No don't remove that. It was just for understanding.

Comment: Also you if condition i gave was just some hardcoded values. This needs to be made generic. Also if you see the function inside condition is camera.rotation.set () i.e. similar to your cube function with mapping values from deviceorientation listener.

Comment: So I checked and apparently there is a problem with my device - the entire coordinates system is messed up (for example the compass is showing that the north is in the south). The code worked fine on other devices. So the only question left is how to set it to start always from the same point and rotate from it.